# Node JS REST API post request unable to release connection

Tags: node.js, rest, node-oracledb

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
const morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post("/user", function (req, res){
     console.log("Posting data into table :");
     const connection = oracledb.getConnection(
        {
          user          : "SYSTEM",
          password      : "************",
          connectString : "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-*****)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))"
        })
        .then(function(conn) {
          return conn.execute(
            `INSERT INTO table1 (department_id, department_name) VALUES` [req.body.department_id, req.body.department_name]
          )
            .then(function(result) {
              console.log(result.rows);
              res.json(result.rows);
              return conn.close();
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.error(err);
              return conn.close();
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
    connection.release(
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        } else {
            console.log("POST /user_profiles : Connection released");
        }
    });
});
 app.listen(3000, ()=>{
     console.log("Connected . . . ")
 })
```

I am unable to release the connection in the POST program written above, the error is shown as follows :

> Error: NJS-006: invalid type for parameter 1
>       at Object.assert (C:\Node\NodePrograms\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:80:11)
>       at Connection.execute (C:\Node\NodePrograms\node_modules\oracledb\lib\connection.js:129:12)
>       at C:\Node\NodePrograms\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:116:16
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Connection.execute (C:\Node\NodePrograms\node_modules\oracledb\lib\util.js:104:14)
>       at C:\Node\NodePrograms\postdb.js:20:23

I am using ARC of chrome to post the data.Its showing `500 Internal Server Error and <pre>TypeError: connection.release is not a function` I am using Node JS and Oracle DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Seems there are two different errors here. Let's look at `connection.release is not a function` first.

`oracledb.getConnection` is an async function. It returns `undefined` if the last parameter is a callback function or a promise if the last parameter is not a callback function. In either case, it does not return a connection directly.

Since you didn't pass in a callback function as the last parameter, it's returning a promise. The promise doesn't have a `release` method, hence the error you get when invoking `connection.release`. However, you are already closing the connection with `conn.close` in another code path.

As for `NJS-006: invalid type for parameter 1 at Object.assert`, this is related to your call to `conn.execute` (as indicated in the error stack). Here's what you have:

```
conn.execute(
  `INSERT INTO table1 (department_id, department_name) VALUES` [req.body.department_id, req.body.department_name]
)
```

Notice that you're passing a single value (an expression) to execute, not two parameters as you may have intended (missing the comma). The template literal and the array can result in weird values:

```
console.log(`string` [1]); // "t"
console.log(`string` [{}]); // undefined
```

You're likely passing `undefined` to `conn.execute`. This is one of those "Wat?" moments. :) https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Once you fix that, you'll also need to update your insert statement, which is currently missing the bind variables. See this post (part of a series on  REST APIs) for some pointers: https://jsao.io/2018/04/creating-a-rest-api-handling-post-put-and-delete-requests/